# R loop with sprintf and paste

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, printf, paste

I recently started to work with R to display price forecast from firms and institutions (World Bank, EIA, Deloitte and Macquarie) for different products (USA Natural gas, Japan LNG and NBP gas).
So there is a graph displaying price forcast for the World Bank about USA Natural Gas, another graph for the World Bank about Japan LNG, another one for the World Bank about the NBP gas and so on with the EIA, Deloitte and Macquarie.
So it's 12 graphs for now.

I am trying to write a code with loops to automatically create and save the graphic file but I have some difficulties to make it work.
I am unfortunately struggling with the `sprintf` and `paste` functions, but I really need to use them and I can't figure out a way to get ride of the remaining error messages.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(scales)
    n <- 1
    c1 <- c("USA", "Japan", "NBP")
    c2 <- c("World Bank", "EIA", "Deloitte", "Macquarie")
    for (i in c1)
    {
    for (j in c2)
    {
    sprintf("chemin%d", n) <- "C:\\Travail\\Maxime\\Memoire\\Forecasts\\csv\\paste(i)realizedprice.csv"
    sprintf("%srealizedprice", i) <- data.frame(read.table(sprintf("chemin%d", n), sep=";", dec=",", header=TRUE))
    sprintf("%srealizedprice$Date", i) <- as.Date(sprintf("%srealizedprice$Date", i), format="%d/%m/%Y")
    sprintf("%srealizedpricegraph", i) <- ggplot(data=sprintf("%srealizedprice", i), mapping=aes(x=Date, y=sprintf("%s.price", i))) + geom_line()
    sprintf("%s%sforecast", i, j) <- sprintf("%sforecast", j)[sprintf("%sforecast", j)$Price.type == 'Natural Gas, sprintf("%s", i)',]
    sprintf("%sgraph", i) <- ggplot(data=sprintf("%s%sforecast", i, j), aes(x=Price.date, y=Price, colour=as.character(paste(Price.type, Publication.date))))+geom_line()+geom_point()+geom_line(data = paste(i)realizedprice, aes(x = Date, y = paste(i).price), color = "cornflowerblue")+xlab('Date')+ylab('Price')+ggtitle("sprintf("World Bank forecast for Natural Gas %s", i)")
    sprintf("%sgraph", i) <- sprintf("%sgraph", i) + scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("year"),labels = date_format("%Y"))+scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 25, 1))
    mypath <- file.path(sprintf("C:\\Travail\\Myname\\Memoire\\Forecasts\\Graphs\\Boucle\\%d.png", n))
    paste(i)graph
    png(file=mypath)
    plot(sprintf("%sgraph", i))
    dev.off()
    n <- n + 1
    }
    }
```

Do you have any idea about the way I could make it work?
Thank you very much for your help!

With the error messages, I get :

```
> library(ggplot2)
> library(scales)
> n <- 1
> c1 <- c("USA", "Japan", "NBP")
> c2 <- c("World Bank", "EIA", "Deloitte", "Macquarie")
> for (i in c1)
+ {
+ for (j in c2)
+ {
+ sprintf("chemin %d", n) <- "C:\\Travail\\Maxime\\Memoire\\Forecasts\\csv\\paste(i)realizedprice.csv"
+ sprintf("%srealizedprice", i) <- data.frame(read.table(sprintf("chemin%d", n), sep=";", dec=",", header=TRUE))
+ sprintf("%srealizedprice$Date", i) <- as.Date(sprintf("%srealizedprice$Date", i), format="%d/%m/%Y")
+ sprintf("%srealizedpricegraph", i) <- ggplot(data=sprintf("%srealizedprice", i), mapping=aes(x=Date, y=sprintf("%s.price", i))) + geom_line()
+ sprintf("%s%sforecast", i, j) <- sprintf("%sforecast", j)[sprintf("%sforecast", j)$Price.type == 'Natural Gas, sprintf("%s", i)',]
+ sprintf("%sgraph", i) <- ggplot(data=sprintf("%s%sforecast", i, j), aes(x=Price.date, y=Price, colour=as.character(paste(Price.type, Publication.date))))+geom_line()+geom_point()+geom_line(data = paste(i)realizedprice, aes(x = Date, y = paste(i).price), color = "cornflowerblue")+xlab('Date')+ylab('Price')+ggtitle("sprintf("World Bank forecast for Natural Gas %s", i)")
Erreur : unexpected symbol in:
" == 'Natural Gas, sprintf("%s", i)',]
sprintf("%sgraph", i) <- ggplot(data=sprintf("%s%sforecast", i, j), aes(x=Price.date, y=Price, colour=as.character(paste(Price.type, Publication.date))))+geom_line()+geom_point()+geom_line(dat"
> sprintf("%sgraph", i) <- sprintf("%sgraph", i) + scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("year"),labels = date_format("%Y"))+scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 25, 1))
Error in sprintf("%sgraph", i) + scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("year"),  : 
  argument non numérique pour un opérateur binaire
> mypath <- file.path(sprintf("C:\\Travail\\Maxime\\Memoire\\Forecasts\\Graphs\\Boucle\\%d.png", n))
> paste(i)graph
Erreur : unexpected symbol in "paste(i)graph"
> png(file=mypath)
> plot(sprintf("%sgraph", i))
Error in plot.window(...) : valeurs finies requises pour 'ylim'
De plus : Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
  NAs introduits lors de la conversion automatique
2: In min(x) : aucun argument trouvé pour min ; Inf est renvoyé
3: In max(x) : aucun argument pour max ; -Inf est renvoyé
> dev.off()
windows 
      2 
> n <- n + 1
> }
Erreur : '}' inattendu(e) in "}"
> }
Erreur : '}' inattendu(e) in "}"
```

Comment: I guess `'Natural Gas` should have an end quote.  May be `sprintf("Natural Gas%s", i)`.  Another problem is `sprintf("chemin%d", n) <- ` cannot be on the `lhs` of `<-`  It could be `assign(sprintf("chemin%d", n),  "C:\\Travail\\Maxime\\Memoire\\Forecasts\\csv\\paste(i)realizedprice.csv")`

Comment: I tried to write  == sprintf("Natural Gas%s", i),] but I get  :    Error : unexpected symbol in:
"type == sprintf("Natural Gas%s", i),]
sprintf("%sgraph", i) <- ggplot(data=sprintf("%s%sforecast", i, j), aes(x=Price.date, y=Price, colour=as.character(paste(Price.type, Publication.date))))+geom_line()+geom_point()+geom_line(dat"

Comment: That is what I said you cannot assign `<-` with `sprintf` on the lhs i.e. `sprintf("%s%sforecast", i, j) <-`

Comment: Ok sorry I hadn't seen the second part of your message. Thanks, I will try to fix it.

Comment: I replaced all the sprintf(someting) <-  by assign(sprintf(something), something2)  but I basically get the same error messages.

Comment: I cannot test your code as the datasets are not reproducible.  `"C:\\Travail\\Maxime\\Memoire\\Forecasts\\csv\\paste(i)realizedprice.csv"`  The `paste(i)` looks suspicious.  Did you meant `paste("C:\\Travaial....", i, "realizedpriced.csv", sep="\\")`

Comment: Yes I know it's suspicious because at first I had "C:\\Travail\\Maxime\\Memoire\\Forecasts\\csv\\sprintf(%s, i)realizedprice.csv" but I had an error message and I got ride of it with the paste() function but honestly I can't say why.       
     For example with the USA, I want to get the file "C:\\Travail\\Maxime\\Memoire\\Forecasts\\csv\\USArealizedprice.csv"

Comment: YOu may need `paste("C:\\Travail\\Maxime\\Memoire\\Forecasts\\csv", paste0(i, "realizedprice.csv"), sep="\\")`

Comment: Yes thanks this line works perfectly fine now I could check it. But I stull can't figure out why the = sprintf("Natural Gas%s", i),]) is wrong.

Comment: You have a quote after the sprintf `'Natural Gas, sprintf("%s", i)'` which will not evaluate the `i` in the sprintf

Comment: I changed the line with paste(paste(paste0(j, "forecast"), paste0(j, "forecast$Price.type == "), sep="["), paste("Natural Gas", paste0(i, ""), sep=", "), sep="") . When I test it, it works fine, but I still get an error message for the loop : Erreur : unexpected symbol in:
"ste0(i, ""), sep=", "), sep=""))
assign(sprintf("%sgraph", i), ggplot(data=sprintf("%s%sforecast", i, j), aes(x=Price.date, y=Price, colour=as.character(paste(Price.type, Publication.date))))+geom_line()+geom_point()+geom_lin . Maybe there is a problem in another line.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some lines and I only get one final error message that I don't understand.

```
    > forecast <- data.frame(read.table(chemin, sep=";", dec=",", header=TRUE))
> forecast$Publication.date <- as.Date(forecast$Publication.date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
> forecast$Price.date <- as.Date(forecast$Price.date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
> EIAforecast <- forecast[forecast$Forecaster=="EIA",]
> WorldBankforecast <- forecast[forecast$Forecaster=="World Bank",]
> Macquarieforecast <- forecast[forecast$Forecaster=="Macquarie",]
> Deloitteforecast <- forecast[forecast$Forecaster=="Deloitte",]
> 
> library(ggplot2)
> library(scales)
> n <- 1
> c1 <- c("USA", "Japan", "NBP")
> c2 <- c("WorldBank", "EIA", "Deloitte", "Macquarie")
> for (i in c1)
+ {
+ for (j in c2)
+ {
+ assign(sprintf("%srealizedprice", i), data.frame(read.table(paste("C:\\Travail\\Maxime\\Memoire\\Forecasts\\csv", paste0(i, "realizedprice.csv"), sep="\\"), sep=";", dec=",", header=TRUE)))
+ assign(sprintf("%srealizedprice$Date", i), as.Date(sprintf("%srealizedprice$Date", i), format="%d/%m/%Y"))
+ assign(sprintf("%srealizedpricegraph", i), ggplot(data=sprintf("%srealizedprice", i), mapping=aes(x=Date, y=sprintf("%s.price", i))) + geom_line())
+ assign(sprintf("%s%sforecast", i, j), paste(paste(paste0(j, "forecast"), paste0(j, "forecast$Price.type == "), sep="["), paste("\"Natural Gas", paste0(i, "\"]"), sep=", "), sep=""))
+ assign(sprintf("%sgraph", i), ggplot(data=paste0(i, j, "forecast"), aes(x=Price.date, y=Price, colour=as.character(paste(Price.type, Publication.date))))+geom_line()+geom_point()+geom_line(data = paste0(i, "realizedprice"), aes(x = Date, y = paste(i, "price", sep=".")), color = "cornflowerblue")+xlab('Date')+ylab('Price')+ggtitle(sprintf("World Bank forecast for Natural Gas %s", i)))
+ assign(sprintf("%sgraph", i), sprintf("%sgraph", i) + scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("year"),labels = date_format("%Y"))+scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 25, 1)))
+ mypath <- file.path(sprintf("C:\\Travail\\Maxime\\Memoire\\Forecasts\\Graphs\\Boucle\\%d.png", n))
+ paste0(i, "graph")
+ png(file=mypath)
+ plot(sprintf("%sgraph", i))
+ dev.off()
+ n <- n + 1
+ }
+ }
```

The problem is with the ggplot :

```
> ggplot(data=sprintf("%srealizedprice", i), mapping=aes(x=Date, y=sprintf("%s.price", i))) + geom_line()
Erreur : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character
```